# Ember 2.5 QueryRecord Return's All Records Instead of Only One

Tags: ember-data, ember-cli

I am having a tough time building a test Ember app the right way.   When I hit the main index page, the route succesfully grabs all 7 records from the database, as it should and sticks them in the store.   However, when I go to a single post with the link-to helper and use queryRecord, it still returns all 7 records.   I have tried it with and without the reloadRecord and also tried it with a filter key.

** Standard disclaimer, as always, its most likely something stupid!

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    console.log(params);  //20160422-tutorial
    let post = this.store.queryRecord('post', {slug: params.slug}, { reload: true });
    console.log(post);  //shows all 7 records here and in the ember inspector.
    return post;
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems to me like some other problem, not related to the code, because your code seems fine. Query record returns a single record AFAIK, thus it seems strange you're getting 7 of them. Are you overriding adaper's methods? Do you pass a model instance into your link-in helper or a text (probably ID)?

Comment: I actually figured this out moments ago by adding the :id in the router.js file as path segment... now it works.    What's odd is I didn't change an other code.